# Reverse compute grade from class year

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm looking for a simple way to "reverse engineer" a student's current grade (as in year in school), based on their graduation year inside my Access database.

Note, I'm NOT calculating student grades, such as A+ or B-. My hope is to calculate their current grade, as in "1st grade", "8th grade", or "12th grade", based on their class year.

My table has a ClassYear column, based on the year, such as 2018 or 2024.

The tricky part to this solution is the idea of "current" grade.  It would be easy to know that a student graduating in 2018 is currently, as of the fall of 2017, a senior.  However, because we're looking for a "current" grade based on today's date, we want to base the calculation off of the school year (September 1 - Aug 31) and not the calendar year (Jan 1 - Dec 31).

The class year is sitting populated in a textbox on the student profile, and I hope to have another, locked textbox that displays the "current grade".

My thinking is that, OnLoad, the form would calculate the grade based on today's date, and where it falls in the range of September 1 - Aug 31.

For instance, if a student class year is 2024, and today's date happens to be September 3rd of 2017,  then their current grade would be 6th grade. 
However, if today's date was August 31 of 2017, and that student's class year was 2024, then they would currently be in 5th grade.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this should solve your issue:

```
Function getGrade(StudentYear As Integer) As Integer

    getGrade = 12 - DateDiff("yyyy", Date, DateSerial(StudentYear, 1, 1))
    If Month(Date) > 8 Then getGrade = getGrade + 1
End Function
```

Where StudentYear is the student's graduation year.

In real use, there should be error catching for negative grades or grades over 12 (depending on your jurisdiction).

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you for your quick response. I can definitely handle the error catching.  Your solution is awesome, but I can't get it implemented and working.   
I set up your function as a public module, but I'm having trouble calling it and passing the ClassYear to it.  Any recommendations on triggering it?  I tried it through the form as well as calling the function from with a query, no luck (getting a mismatch).

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not an expert in VBA by any means, so I always put functions in the same module/form as whatever I'm calling them with. If this is the only application you'll have for this function, I don't see how that can hurt. To call it from another module, use the following syntax: `gradeModule.getGrade()` where gradeModule is the module that the getGrade function is in.

Comment: Awesome.  Got it working perfectly and populating the textbox.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @prsaddict Don't forget to mark the correct answer and upvote it.